# Check an array have string?

Tags: javascript

```
setTimeout(function() {
             abc[index].Factoid 
                }, 2000);
```

I set some string in this array.

How to check this array has string or has no string?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array.length > 0) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$.each(array-name , function(){
  return typeof this === 'string' ? true : false
});
```

Comment: How do you console.log true or false with your method to test an array if it has a string? I can't get a successful test.